# GIMP crashes when I try to load OpenEXR Multilayer FLoat(full) files

Tags: gimp, blender

I have exported OpenEXR Multilayer RGBA Float (full) in ZIP codec from BLender, but when I want to open them in Gimp, it gives me this error message(it is in german sorry):

[image]

But when I export it as OpenEXR without multilayer, then it works.
(I need the multilayer for the associated alpha transparency)

Command Prompt: (after starting gimp with: gimp-2.10.exe --console-messages --debug-handlers)(And sorry for the german)

```
    gimp-2.10.exe: LibGimpBase-WARNUNG: gimp-2.10.exe: gimp_wire_read(): error
    GIMP-Fehler: Das Plugin »file-exr.exe« ist abgestürzt
    (D:\Programme\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\file-exr\file-exr.exe)

    Das abgestürzte Plugin hat GIMP eventuell instabil gemacht. Sie sollten sicherheitshalber Ihre Bilder jetzt abspeichern und anschließend GIMP neu starten.

    GIMP-Fehler: Das Öffnen von »D:\Fire EXR test\EXR\EXR_Test.exr« ist fehlgeschlagen:

    Prozedur »file-exr-load« hat sich ohne Rückgabewerte beendet

    gimp-2.10.exe: LibGimpBase-WARNUNG: gimp-2.10.exe: gimp_wire_read(): error
    GIMP-Fehler: Das Plugin »file-exr.exe« ist abgestürzt
    (D:\Programme\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\file-exr\file-exr.exe)

    Das abgestürzte Plugin hat GIMP eventuell instabil gemacht. Sie sollten sicherheitshalber Ihre Bilder jetzt abspeichern und anschließend GIMP neu starten.

GIMP-Fehler: Das Öffnen von »D:\Fire EXR test\EXR\EXR_Test.exr« ist fehlgeschlagen:
```

Comment: I suggest you open a terminal and run `gimp` from the command line. That will probably give more information on the crash, that you can then share in the question.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the delay. How do I open gimp in a terminal do I just open a terminal in the folder where the exe is and type the name of the exe and hit enter? @EduardoTrápani

Comment: Okay, I added further detail to the main Post @EduardoTrápani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multilayer EXR files aren't supported in the GIMP 2.10 versions.